# Awaiting a predicate with C++20 coroutines

Tags: c++, c++20, coroutine, c++-coroutine

We started using the modern C++20 coroutines on our project recently. There is a list of coroutines referred to as Tasks in the Executor, which steps through them one by one resuming them. All of this is done on a single thread. Sometimes coroutines need not to be resumed until some predicate is satisfied. In some cases it may be satisfied by another coroutine, which makes suspending for later execution just fine.
Here are the types in use:

```cpp
struct Task : std::coroutine_handle<task_promise_t> {
  using promise_type = task_promise_t;
};
```

```cpp
struct task_promise_t {
  Task get_return_object() { return {Task::from_promise(*this)}; }
  std::suspend_always initial_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
  std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }

  void return_void() {}
  void unhandled_exception() {}
};
```

```cpp
struct Executor {
  /* snip */

  void enqueue_task(Task &&task) { tasks.push_back(task); }

  void tick() {
    while (!tasks.empty())
      this->step();
  }

  void step() {
    Task task = std::move(tasks.front());
    tasks.pop_front();
    task.resume();
    if (!task.done())
      tasks.push_back(task);
  }

  std::deque<Task> tasks;

  /* snip */
}
```

Example of how I expect it to be used:

```cpp
auto exec = Executor();

static bool global_predicate = false;

exec.enqueue_task([](Executor* exec) -> Task {
  co_await WaitFor(/* bool(void) */ []() -> bool { return global_predicate; });
  /* prerequisite satisfied, other logic goes here */
  std::cout << "Hello, world" << std::endl;
}(&exec));
```

```cpp
exec.step(); // no output, predicate false
exec.step(); // no output, predicate false
global_predicate = true;
exec.step(); // predicate true, "Hello, world!", coroutine is also done
```

I did manage to get the implementation going, this seems to work fine.

```cpp
static bool example_global_predicate;
auto coro = []() -> Task {
  while (!example_global_predicate)
    co_await std::suspend_always();
  /* example_global_predicate is now true, do stuff */
  co_return;
}();
```

But I can't a good way to generalize and abstract it into it's own class. How would one go about it? I would expect to see that functionality in the standard library, but seeing how customizable the coroutines are I doubt there is a way to implement a one-size-fits-all solution.

Comment: "*How would one go about it?*" Why would you want this? Polling is, broadly speaking, not a great way to go about any continuation-based async programming. It may sometimes be necessary, but it is best to avoid it where possible. The broad idea behind `co_await` coroutines is that you await on the specific thing that you're actually waiting on. That is, you register your continuation with whatever process is going to activate this "global predicate", and instead of setting some value, it will just wake up whatever tasks are waiting on it.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I do agree that polling may be sub optimal. This global predicate turning true usually means release of a resource. My specific case attempts to mimic a behavior of a read-write semaphore which I can not employ in full power since the tasks may be executed on a single thread, the predicate being "resource is free to read" or "resource is free to write to".

Comment: "*This global predicate turning true usually means release of a resource.*" And that means that some process caused the release of that resource. In the coroutine model, *that process* is the one that needs to activate the waiting tasks. That's how the coroutine model is structured, and that's why `co_await` is an *expression* rather than a statement. It unpacks a value precisely because the idea is that the process that generated some information is then handing it to you.

Comment: despite this doesn't sound best idea, I fail to see how generalize would fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "await" style of coroutines is intended for doing asynchronous processing in a way that mirrors the synchronous equivalent. In sinchronous code, you might write:

```
int func(float f)
{
   auto value = compute_stuff(f);
   auto val2 = compute_more_stuff(value, 23);
   return val2 + value;
}
```

If one or both of these functions is asychronous, you would rewrite it as follows (assuming the presence of appropriate `co_await` machinery):

```
task<int> func(float f)
{
   auto value = compute_stuff(f);
   auto val2 = co_await async_compute_more_stuff(value, 23);
   co_return val2 + value;
}
```

It's structurally the same code except that in one case, `func` will halt halfway through until `async_compute_more_stuff` has finished its computation, then be resumed and return its value through `Task<int>`. The async nature of the code is as implicit as possible; it largely looks like synchronous code.

If you already have some extant async process, and you just want a function to get called when that process concludes, and there is no direct relationship between them, you don't need a coroutine. This code:

```
static atomic<bool> example_global_predicate;
auto coro = []() -> Task {
  while (!example_global_predicate)
    co_await std::suspend_always();
  /* example_global_predicate is now true, do stuff */
  co_return;
}();
```

Is not meaningfully different from this:

```
static atomic<bool> example_global_predicate;

register_polling_task([]() -> bool
{
  if(!example_global_predicate)
     return false;
  /* example_global_predicate is now true, do stuff */
  return true;
});
```

`register_polling_task` represents some global construct which will at regular intervals call your function until it returns `true`, at which point it assumes that it has done its job and removes the task. Your coroutine version might hide this global construct, but it still needs to be there because *somebody* has to wake the coroutine up.

Overall, this is not an async circumstance where using coroutines buys you anything in particular.

However, it could still be theoretically useful to attach coroutine resumption to a polling task. The most reasonable way to do this is to put the polling in a task outside of a coroutine. That is, coroutines shouldn't poll for the global state; that's someone else's job.

A coroutine would do something like `co_await PollingTask()`. This hands the `coroutine_handle` off to the system that polls the global state. When that global state enters the correct state, it will resume that handle. And when executing the `co_await` expression, it should also check the state then, so that if the state is already signaled, it should just not halt the coroutine's execution.

`PollingTask()` would return an awaitable that has all of this machinery built into it.